# Show fields based on user_ID in table project_users

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

[image]

This is my database and I'm trying to find out a query. My query should print out the project values name, description and image based on the `user_id` in `project_users`. The projects are connected via the tasks.

How would I go about fetching the project values based on the `user_ID` that's connected with `task_ID` which leads to `project_ID` via the `project_task` table?

`project_ID` in `project` is 2, `project_ID` for the task in `project_task` is 2 and the `task_ID` is 3 while the `task_ID` in `project_users` is 3.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables and have a condition for the `user_id` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.project_name,
                p.project_description,
                p.project_image
       FROM project p
            INNER JOIN project_task t
                       ON t.project_id = p.project_id
            INNER JOIN project_users pu
                       ON pu.task_id = t.task_id
       WHERE pu.user_id = <user id>;
```